# How to show source.Vector from geojsonObject in openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geojson

I am doing tests with openlayers and i don't know how to show source.Vector that contains a Point in my map. It works fine when i get the geojson from 'url' but no in this way. (Blue circle should appear but nothing appears)

```
var geojsonObject = new ol.Feature ({
              "type": "FeatureCollection",
              "features": [
                {
                  "type": "Feature",
                  "properties": {},
                  "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                      self.coords[0].latitude,
                      self.coords[1].longitude
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            });

            var source = new ol.source.Vector({
                features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
            });

var map = new ol.Map({
                target: 'map',
                layers: [
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                        title: 'Global Imagery',
                        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                            url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
                            params: {LAYERS: 'nasa:bluemarble', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
                        })
                    }),
                    new ol.layer.Vector({
                        title: 'Location',
                        source: source,
                        style: new ol.style.Style({
                            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                                radius: 5,
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color: '#0000FF'
                                }),
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: '#000000'
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
                ],
                view: new ol.View({
                    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                    center: [0, 0],
                    zoom: 1
                })
            });
```

Where is the problem? the style is not well implemented maybe?
thanks in advance!

I followed parts of this example: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html

Codepen: http://codepen.io/ricopo/pen/zBVXbq

Comment: Solved: The geojsonObject definition must be without "new ol.Feature". But just: geojsonObect = { }